# REGEX for removing PHP Parameter in URL from Google Analytics

Tags: php, regex, url, google-analytics

I need to create a regular expression for removing a url php parameter in a google analytics filter but I am not equipped with the right skills!

We have a site that appends the following string to urls

?currency=USD etc

Just need to regex for this if anybody is able to help

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the parameter is not being used by your application? Surely the site will just append the parameter when it is reloaded??

Comment: Yes it is being used. I need to exclude from Google Analytics via their filters. I need a regex explicity for filtering their data don't want to do anything to how the website is functioning

Comment: For reference: http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/04/17/strip-query-parameters-google-analytics/

Comment: Do you want to remove all parameters, or just the currency one?

Comment: Just the currency parameter which appears for each of USD, GBP and EUR

Comment: I'd remove it at the request level, .htaccess or web.config.

Comment: According to the information you provided via the link, you need two:  (currency=[^&]*&?) - Removes the currency item and ([?&]$) removes any trailing & or question mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation in the [link](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/04/17/strip-query-parameters-google-analytics/) you provided, it seems quite simple:

```
(currency=[^&]*&?)
```

> The first part is the query’s **currency** and the ‘=’. Keep in mind that the
>   query may be one of many and between or before other queries that we
>   want to remain. The next part of the expression, ‘[^&]’, is targeting
>   any character that is not an ampersand so that it stops before the
>   next query. The asterisk is there representing 0 or more of the
>   preceding character, so it will cover us if it is the last query. If
>   there’s an ampersand after the query parameter, we also want to remove
>   it to prevent something like this from showing up
>   “/blog/post-23?lang=en&&x1=key4929”.

Again, in the documentation, they indicate how to remove the trailing `?` and `&` signs with a simple filter:

```
([?&]$)
```

Comment: This seems to have worked apart from I'm still seeing the question mark at the beginning?

Comment: @StuartLeech See my updated answer. If it has worked then don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: This seemed to do it: (\?currency=[^&]*&?)